# django filter - How to search a phone number form 3 columns

Tags: django, django-filter

Here is my model:

```
HomePhone = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
Phone2 = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
Phone3 = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
```

Here is the filter:

```
class optionFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = option2019
        fields = {
            'LastName': ['icontains',],
            'FirstName':['icontains',],
            'aidecode':['exact',],
            'SSN':['icontains',],
            'HomePhone':['exact',],
            }
```

From the model, every one would have 3 phone numbers. How do I get the filter to look for all 3 phone number columns and return all info for the 1 person?

Thank you!

Comment: @DeadSec Please avoid these trivial edits that achieve nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare a custom filter and use the [`method` argument](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#customize-filtering-with-filter-method). In your case it would be something like

```py
import django_filters
from django.db.models import Q


class optionFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    phone = django_filters.CharFilter(method='phone_filter')

    class Meta:
        model = option2019
        fields = {
            'LastName': ['icontains',],
            'FirstName':['icontains',],
            'aidecode':['exact',],
            'SSN':['icontains',],
            'phone': ['exact',],
            }

    def phone_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(Q(HomePhone=value) | Q(Phone2=value) | Q(Phone3=value))
```